# identify PNGs in SVG's clothing

Tags: png, svg, image-processing

I sometimes encounter "faux" SVGs, i.e., SVG images files that simply list pixels as `path`s:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1295" height="573">
  <path fill="#FEFEFE" d="M143 1h1V0h-1Zm0 0" />
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M144 1h33V0h-33Zm0 0" />
  <path fill="#FEFEFE" d="M177 1h1V0h-1Zm0 0" />
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M178 1h67V0h-67Zm0 0" />
  <path fill="#FEFEFE" d="M245 1h1V0h-1Zm0 0" />
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M246 1h12V0h-12Zm0 0" />
  <path fill="#FEFEFE" d="M258 1h1V0h-1Zm0 0" />
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M259 1h1036V0H259ZM0 2h180V1H0Zm0 0" />
  <path fill="#FEFEFE" d="M180 2h1V1h-1Zm0 0" />
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M181 2h10V1h-10Zm0 0" />
  <path fill="#FEFEFE" d="M191 2h1V1h-1Zm0 0" />
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M192 2h92V1h-92Zm0 0" />
  ...
```

Needless to say, storing and downloading these files is unnecessarily costly, so I'd like to identify such files and convert them to PNGs.

How would I best go about identifying such faux SVGs?